# R "Packages" vs Linux packages for R

Tags: r, package, opensuse

I'm a little confused about what is going on when I install packages within R.

I start R (from the terminal, via "R"), and then at the R prompt, I do this:

```
> install.packages("devtools")
```

R goes off, and downloads quite a few things, launches a C/C++ compiler against dozens of source files, appears to build stuff successfully, but eventually fails with a message like this:

```
ERROR: dependencies ‘usethis’, ‘pkgdown’, ‘rcmdcheck’, ‘rversions’, ‘urlchecker’ are not available for package ‘devtools’
```

This is quite confusing, because I expect R to handle the dependencies.

Then I wonder, have I failed to install R correctly ?
Looking at the list of R packages available (for OpenSuse Tumbleweed via zypper), I can see that there are about 50 packages with names like "R-base-devel", "R-graphics", "R-tools", etc..  These are somehow distinct from R's internal conception of a package.  It's totally unclear how these Linux packages are related to the R internal packages, and if perhaps I am missing one of them.

I installed R via zypper by way of "sudo zypper install R-recommended-packages", which of course pulled in quite a few dependencies, so I guess I have a valid environment.  But, clearly, I am missing something

How does this all hang together ?   How do I know which linux package for R contains which R package ?

I wasn't expecting this to be quite a confusing and complicated.

Comment: Some packages have system dependencies, which can't typically be installed automatically. Those that failed will often give a helpful message about how to correctly configure your system (e.g. an apt-get invocation).

Comment: usually if you run install.packages() again, the error message will be clearer as it won't get lost in the miles and miles of compiler output from the packages that installed OK. You can also check the SystemRequirements field for the package on CRAN, e.g. for xml2 https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xml2/index.html

Comment: The other thing you can do is to try to install the "missing" packages one by one.  Often it is just one or two of them that are problematic; the others depend on them.

Comment: WOW !!!!

Very helpful - that did indeed make it "easier" to see the problems.  I am now looking at only 164 lines of output, and scattered throughout those lines are lines like this:    Configuration failed because libcurl was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libcurl4-openssl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: libcurl-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)   And, of course, Configuration failed to find the fontconfig freetype2 library. Try installing:
 * deb: libfontconfig1-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: fontconfig-devel (Fedora, EPEL)

totally different formats !!!!!!

Comment: I know R is used by some serious people, and some of the R functionality is very impressive, but, the package management looks like a complete mess to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All R packages are available in source format.  That source code can be just plain R, or include stuff in other languages, such as C, C++, or Fortran.  While R source code does not need to be pre-compiled to run, stuff in other languages often does.  This means that when a package containing C or C++ source code is installed, that code needs to be compiled into binaries.  This means that any environment installing R packages *from source* needs to have the appropriate toolset (compiler, linker, etc) and libraries *including dependencies* such as Boost.  To avoid this, and to speedup the installing process, R packages are also made available in *binary* form, for some platforms (Windows and macOS being two notable cases).

Linux distributions run on multiple architectures and aren't consistent in how they make their libraries available, so it is not practical to distribute binary R packages (except perhaps for some well known and widely used distributions, and this happens with a lot of software, not just R packages). So in most cases, R packages must be installed from source, and compiled upon installation.  To ease things, some Linux distributions pack sets of R packages in their own package system, so that's why you find things like `R-graphics` and `R-recommended-packages` on the repository of your OS.  And you are absolutely right in your understanding that these OS packages are not the same thing as R packages.

R packages can be found either on centralized repositories, such as CRAN (the official repository for R packages), or Bioconductor, as standalone files.  Nowadays you can also just pull a copy of a git repository and build the package from there.  This is not to be confused with the repository for OS packages.

When you issue the command `install.packages("foo")` in R, it will search R repositories for package `foo`.  If it's available in binary form for your platform and OS, it will install that. Otherwise, it will download the source code, compile it if necessary, and install it.  By default, R will search the CRAN repository indicated by `options('repos')`, but you can add others.

Now if the package you are compiling has some external dependencies (such as libxml or libcurl), you'll need to make them available on your system, as @MichaelChirico noted on his comments.  So you'll need to find you the requirements of those packages and install via your OS's package management system (e.g. `zypper`).  You will need the development versions for each library (in Linux they often are `-dev` or `-devel` packages). This is another advantage of the OS distributing it own sets of pre-built R packages, such as `R-recommended-packages`: their dependencies are automatically installed by the OS's package management system.

The errors you are seeing are probably due to some of the R packages being installed (perhaps dependencies of the R packages you want) failing to compile, and thus to be installed.  You'll need to find out their external requirements and install them first.

Comment: That's a very informative and helpful comment.  Many Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

@MichaelChirico gave good advice about how to diagnose the issues here.  I'll try to answer the question about what "packages" are.

Both R and Linux share the idea of packages as collections of files (code and other things) that depend on each other.  For the R `devtools` package to work, other R packages need to be installed, and `install.packages()` tries to ensure they are.  Similarly, for each Linux package, you may need other Linux packages to get them to work.

However, R packages can also depend on having system files present, for example system libraries to handle graphics, etc.  When you try to install an R package with such a "system dependency", it will fail if the dependency is missing.  R doesn't try to install the system dependency because the method to install system libraries varies so much from platform to platform.  Some R packages will try to give an informative message about how to install the system library yourself.  On Linux this would typically be instructions to install a Linux package:  you saw an example of this.  Other R packages just fail in the installation, with messages like "libcurl not found".

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  </br>  I guess my real question is more like, how can I know which linux package contains the associated R package ?

Comment: That depends on the particular Linux distribution.  I think many R packages aren't in any Linux package at all.  I am only an occasional Linux user, so I don't know their conventions, but it requires someone to do extra work to make a Linux package that contains an R package, so it's only going to happen for some of them.  I would use the R functions to install R packages.

Comment: OK, this was kind of my suspicion.  BUT, thanks for the response